# $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}. f(x) = 0$."take all decimals of x with an even index".

Tags: derivatives, continuity

I remember this function from when I tried (and failed) a math study 20 years ago.

The function $f$ is a function from $ \mathbb{R}$ to $ \mathbb{R}$. In base 10, it copies the number before the decimal separator and from after the decimal separator it copies all decimals at even places and concatenates them to form the output number. For example:

$f(555.11223344559697989900) = 555.1234567890$

1. Does this function (or a similar one) have a name? Where can I find more info?

I vaguely remember that this function had some interesting properties, but I cannot reconstruct them.

2. Is this a continuous function? When applying the definition of continuity I find on Wikipedia, it seems continuous.
3. Is this function differentiable? Again, when I apply the definition of differentiability myself it seems differentiable.

Perhaps (2) and (3) were the "interesting properties", as they were somewhat surprising for me.

Comment: By "decimals" you mean "decimal digits", right? What is $f(1/2)$?

Comment: Maybe you're vaguely remembering the Cantor function, which is continuous and has derivative 0 almost everywhere, but is not constant?  And is constructed in a roughly similar way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to be a bit careful with your definition, because for example
$$ 0.2159999\ldots \qquad\text{and}\qquad 0.216000\ldots $$
which represent the same real number $\frac{27}{125}$, would lead to two different outputs ($0.1999\ldots$ and $0.1000\ldots$) by your description. So it doesn't quite manage to define a *function* from the real numbers.

There are ways to patch things up to work around this problem, but depending on what you want to *use* the function for, you might prefer different patching-up tactics, and they'd lead to slightly different functions.

I don't think the function has a nice short name. One could describe it as *one of the projections corresponding to Cantor's digit-interlacing pairing function*, or something like that. It is most often encountered in connection with an argument that once can define a one-to-one correspondence between $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R$. (In fancier words, $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R$ have the same cardinality).

It is not continuous -- as the above example illustrates, there is no hope of $f(x)$ having a limit as $x\to\frac{27}{125}$.

Since it is not continuous, it cannot be differentiable.

Comment: It seems that the function (after some patch) is discontinuous and non-differentiable in "only" countably many points. Still no hope for a fix?

Comment: @AlbertHendriks: If, for example, you declare that you don't use input representations that end with infinite repeating nines, then you get a function that is _continuous_ at all but countably many points -- but it still won't be differentiable _anywhere_. Whether there is "hope" depends on what your _goal_ is, which is not clear to me.